# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{p=2}^na_{p}=\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

For every natural number $p\geq2$ we have a real number $$a_{p}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{p^{1+k}+p^{-k}+p+1}$$. Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{p=2}^na_{p}=\frac{3}{4}$$
I think this problem is wrong because by induction we can se that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{p^{1+k}+p^{-k}+p+1}=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{2(p-1)(p^{n+1}+1)}$$ so $a_{p}=\frac{1}{2(p-1)}$. So the final result will be the limit of $\frac{1}{2}H_{n-1}$ which is $\infty$. There is something messed up?

Comment: Something does seem wrong ... even the $k=0$ term in the definition of $a_p$ is already about $\frac1{2p}$, which is enough to cause divergence in the sum over $p$.

Comment: Yeah I know. This problem is from Mathematical Gazette. They usually don't have wrong problems.

Comment: Very strange problem.

Comment: Which volume and page of the Mathematical Gazette, please? (or preferably: can you include a screenshot in your post?)